# What is this notation: $f \in C[a, b]$

Tags: notation

This one. Does it stand for "$g$ is continuous over $[a, b]$"?

[image: strange notation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. $C[a,b]$ is the set of all continuous real valued functions with domain $[a,b]$.

Comment: So `C` is a set, like `R`? Could you provide a link about this notation?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa No. $C[a,b]$ is a set: the set of functions which have domain $[a,b]$, codomain (usually) $\Bbb R$ and which are continuous.

Comment: $C[a,b]=\{f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R} : f $ is continuous $\}$ is a set of functions, you can see it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Functional_analysis
and here:
http://www.math.pitt.edu/~sph/1540/1540-notes1.pdf
@MinhNghĩa